# How do I uninstall Kubuntu and install Ubuntu?

Tags: uninstall

I want to uninstall Kubuntu and install Ubuntu, but I want to completely clear former installation first. How do I do it most unharmfully?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can install on top of the Kubuntu installation without any preparation. Simply insert the disk, boot it, and when asked to partition, select "Replace existing Linux installations" or similar. It works like a charm.