# Removing Ubuntu from a dual-boot setup with Windows

Tags: dual-boot, uninstall

I have installed Ubuntu as another OS on my laptop, and my default OS is Windows 7. I just want to know how to remove (or uninstall) Ubuntu without harming the other OS.

PS: Ubuntu and Windows 7 are both installed on one drive.

Comment: Related (possible duplicate): http://askubuntu.com/q/83403/18612

Comment: Also: http://askubuntu.com/q/15234/18612

Comment: regarding the duplicates.. one is specific to a netbook.. which isn't the case here.. 
the other has instructions for an older windows version.. and might not apply.. as windows 7 as a better way to fix inconsistencies.. (boot recovery..)

Answer (score 4):

If you didn't install Ubuntu from within Windows, here's what you'll need to do:

- Boot up your Win 7 disk.
- Go to Boot Recovery and let it do it's thing
- Boot back into Windows and go to Disk Manager
- Delete the two Ubuntu partitions
- Resize your NTFS filesystem to take up the disk.

That easy!

Answer (score 3):

is your ubuntu installed using wubi ? if so .. in W7 just go to "Control Panel" ,then in "Programs and Features" let the list of software load..
when it is loaded.. just click ubuntu and click remove...

if not.. just go to the grub menu.. choose to boot into you W7 partition..and do like told in the answer above ..

Comment: Doesn't sound like a Wubi install. But thanks for that info, I've never done a Wubi install so now I know how to answer this question in the future.

Comment: well.. since your answer only said what to do if ubuntu isn't installed from windows.. i gave the complementary answer.. for those that did install from windows...
the wubi install is pretty forward.. it creates a folder at the root of the C drive and creates a disk file that it (thanks to fuse) enables as a hard drive.. and installs the ubuntu install onto it..then changes to a grub menu you can load from.. removing it from the control panel removes the grub and deletes the folder..one common mistake is just to delete the folder.. which can potentially make problems and make the system slower

Answer (score 0):

For anyone searching an answer and is running Windows 10, You need not the install media. Simply:

> Press windows key on the key board and type "Recovery options"
>
> Press the enter key on your keyboard

or

> Select the dialogue box in the lower right corner and press "All
>   Settings"
>
> Then select Utility & Security, then "Recovery" from the side panel options.

Once inside the Recovery window, Select

> "Restart Now"

under "Advance Start-up"

When the PC restart, there will be three options:

> Choose the second option

(the option that does not turn the pc off or does not go back into Windows 10).

After doing Follow the on screen options Until you arrive at advance options. Select the command line option and restart.

When the system restarts, boot into windows form the GRUB options.

From there the command line pops up... enter:

> bootrec /fixmbr

Press enter

then type:

> bootrec.exe /fixboot

Press enter and the type

> exit

The system will restart into windows and GRUB is now gone. Remember to remove any live disk, if any.

Answer (score -1):

this link describes a method for removing linux and restoring your disk to MBR from GPT:
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/20864-mbr-restore-windows-7-master-boot-record.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.