# How do I boot Ubuntu off a DVD?

Tags: boot, windows-7, dvd, cd-image

I've burnt the Ubuntu 12.10 image onto a DVD and I'm not sure what to do next. How do I boot off of it and can I go back to Windows 7 when I'm done with Ubuntu? I used this as my tutorial:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-dvd-on-windows

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It depends on your computer/laptop's brand name and model. You must hit the proper BOOT Menu key in order to choose the DVD Boot and/or configure your BIOS to do the first boot on DVD. The majority of the equipments does it by default. So if you wish simply reboot with the DVD in your DVD-RW Drive. If it doesn't boot please provide your computer brand name and model in order to receive further support on booting from DVD. Good luck!

Comment: Take a look at [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD) if you want to have a step-by-step set of instructions that you can always refer to.

Comment: From [our nicely illustrated guide](http://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/how-do-i-set-up-a-dual-boot-windows-and-ubuntu) follow to the step where you can choose ***"Try Ubuntu"*** rather than *"Install"*

Comment: This question may be a duplicate of [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows) At least the first part. You can dual boot for now. If you later decide to get rid of Ubuntu that's covered in this question [Removing Ubuntu from a dual-boot setup with Windows](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110425/removing-ubuntu-from-a-dual-boot-setup-with-windows)