# How can I remove kubuntu-Desktop  completely from Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, kde, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I uninstall Kubuntu and install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15234/how-do-i-uninstall-kubuntu-and-install-ubuntu)

I installed **kde** desktop on my Ubuntu installation to try it and I like unity more and for space concerns I need to remove it. How to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered on the superuser stackexchange - see https://superuser.com/questions/30112/kubuntu-to-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

here is one [link](http://complete-concrete-concise.com/ubuntu-2/ubuntu-12-04/ubuntu-12-04-how-to-completely-uninstallremove-a-packagesoftwareprogram)

refer this link .hope you got your answer.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.